# AWS routing between AZs

Tags: amazon-web-services, routing, amazon-vpc, site-to-site-vpn

There's three subnets:

- subnet A on AZ-A, 10.0.1.0/24
- subnet B on AZ-B, 10.0.2.0/24
- subnet C on AZ-C, 10.0.3.0/24

There's one server on subnet A (10.0.1.50) answering to ping performed via Site-to-Site VPN.

Is it somehow possible to route pings to this one and only server also when pinging to 10.0.2.50 or 10.0.3.50?

Comment: Off the top of my head there's no easy way do to that.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me...

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the CIDR of both subnets in the security groups of the instances as indicated by the AWS documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#DefaultSecurityGroup

You can also follow the step by step described in the following documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario3.html